# What happened to Cope?

Tags: album

What happened with Manchester Orchestra’s album [*Cope*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cope_%28Manchester_Orchestra_album%29) that it doesn’t seem to be available for streaming anywhere anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably they'd rather push the newer album, Hope

It's on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDPnVRspo_0

iTunes - https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/manchester-orchestra/id80919241

Title track on [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/manchesterorchestra), but mainly Hope.

Answer (score 1):

From their official Youtube channel : [Manchester Orchestra: COPE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDPnVRspo_0).